# Splitting a row into 2 rows based on value present in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, oracle12c

I got a requirement to split one record into two records based on values in a column.

Sample Input:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+------------------+
| REC_KEY | SURR_KEY  | REC_YR | MANUFACTURER | MODEL_NAME |    ENG_POWER     |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+------------------+
|   12345 | 615099386 |   2003 | BMW          | Z8         | 4.8L V8; 4.9L V8 |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+------------------+
```

Sample Output:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| REC_KEY | SURR_KEY  | REC_YR | MANUFACTURER | MODEL_NAME | ENG_POWER |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|   12345 | 615099386 |   2003 | BMW          | Z8         | 4.8L V8   |
|   12345 | 615099386 |   2003 | BMW          | Z8         | 4.9L V8   |
+---------+-----------+--------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split value of that column by `;` character through use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, while counting the number of that characters by `REGEXP_COUNT()` function

```
 SELECT rec_key, surr_key, rec_yr, manufacturer, model_name, 
        TRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR(eng_power,'[^;]+',1,level) ) AS eng_power 
   FROM tab 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(eng_power,';') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR rec_key = rec_key
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0e81eb70259b9ffcbf2edfa799a0ba95)</kbd>

Comment: I think that would have issues if it operated on more than one row at a time

Answer (score 0):

try this SQL Script :

```
with cte(a,b,c,d,e,f) as 
( select 12345 , 615099386 ,  2003 ,'BMW','Z8','4.8L V8; 4.9L V8' from dual)
select a,b,c,d,e,
ltrim(regexp_substr(f,'[^;]+',1,level)) as f from cte
connect by level<=length(f)-length(replace(f,';',''))+1;
```